# How to use Vue3 like readonly on Vue2

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt2 and '@nuxtjs/composition-api'.

This '@nuxtjs/composition-api' has readonly() function, however this not behave like [Vue3 readonly](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#readonly)

When you use '@nuxtjs/composition-api' readonly, you can actually change that value.
I'd like to use Vue3 readonly function or some function which has same behavior.

On the other hand, as for shallowReadonly(), both versions behave like the same.
Therefore you can use shallowReadonly(), if the target is not nested object.

But I'd like to use it for nested object in this time.

If someone knows this solution, please answer!

Comment: typescript (typescript)

Comment: Perhaps applying `Object.freeze()` recursively on the nested Objects?